# Animating a number with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a simple game and I need to animate the points gathered.

Currently what I did was:

```
if (selectedWord == item)
{
    gamePoints = gamePoints+5;
    $(".gameSpanStarImage").html(gamePoints);
}
```

Can you tell me how to create an animation effect on the number? I know that I need to use some kind of animation like:

```
<div id="button">Click me</div><br>

<div id="container">Faded in</div>

<script>
  $("#container").hide();

  $("#button").click(function() {$("#container").fadeIn()});
</script>
```

But it shouldn't happen on click but rather when the score changes.

Comment: use this http://www.jquery4u.com/animation/5-jquery-number-animation-plugins/

Comment: Check the updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/cVELa/19/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
if (selectedWord == item) {
    $({number:gamePoints}).animate({number:gamePoints+5}, {step:function(now,fx){
        $(".gameSpanStarImage").html(parseInt(now));
    }})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `fadeIn()`... you need to `hide()` an element before fading it in..
try this

```
 if (selectedWord == item)
{
  gamePoints = gamePoints+5;
  $(".gameSpanStarImage").hide().html(gamePoints).fadeIn('slow');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple number counter:

```
$.fn.animatedCounter = function(from, to, speed) {
  var self = this;

  function setText(text) {
    return function(){ self.text(text); };
  }

  for (var i=from; i<=to; i++) {
    setTimeout(setText(i), i*(speed/to));
  }
};

$('div').animatedCounter(1,100,5000); // Count from 1 to 100 in 5 seconds
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/ocowab/1/edit